# Multiple form sign up not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a sign up process which involves two forms being submitted. The problem is with the first form not being submitted. Also, I need a way to relate the two forms as information from both is inserted into the same table row, I think this can be done by taking the previous table row id.

It is supposed to work like this: First a user must search for an item in the search bar. Matches are then displayed with radio buttons next to each one and a submit button at the bottom. When submitted, the form data (which is the result of the search that they checked with the radio) goes into the database table 'users'. The 'users' table contains a row for id, username, password and radio.

The radio option is submitted into radio. This also creates an id, which is auto incremented. That is the first form. Once the radio option is picked and the data is in a table row, the user must fill out the second form which asks for an email and a password, which is submitted into the same row that the radio option is in.

When I go through this process, the email (referred to as username in table) and password appear in the table along with the id, but the radio is always blank. Not sure why the radio option is not being submitted. Also not sure if i need a way to relate the forms. I am a beginner at this so, please try to make answers understandable. Thanks in advance, heres the code:

```
<?php
       //This code runs if the form has been submitted

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 



 //This makes sure they did not leave any fields blank

 if (!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['pass'] | !$_POST['pass2'] ) {

        die('You did not complete all of the required fields');

    }



 // checks if the username is in use

    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

        $_POST['username'] = addslashes($_POST['username']);

    }

 $usercheck = $_POST['username'];

 $check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$usercheck'") 

or die(mysql_error());

 $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);



 //if the name exists it gives an error

 if ($check2 != 0) {

        die('The email '.$_POST['username'].' is already in use.');

                }


 // this makes sure both passwords entered match

    if ($_POST['pass'] != $_POST['pass2']) {

        die('Your passwords did not match. ');

    }



    // here we encrypt the password and add slashes if needed

    $_POST['pass'] = md5($_POST['pass']);

    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

        $_POST['pass'] = addslashes($_POST['pass']);

        $_POST['username'] = addslashes($_POST['username']);

            }

 // now we insert it into the database
    $insert = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, radio)
            VALUES ('".$_POST['username']."', '".$_POST['pass']."', '".$_POST['radio']."')";
    $add_member = mysql_query($insert);
?>

 <h2><font color="red">Registered</font></h2>
 <p>Thank you, you have registered - you may now login</a>.</p>
<?php 
} 
else 
{   
?>
<font color = #000000><h1>Sign Up</h1></font>
<?php
// Search Engine
// Only execute when button is pressed
if (isset($_POST['keyword'])) {
// Filter
$keyword = trim ($_POST['keyword']);

// Select statement
$search = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cause_name LIKE '%$keyword%'";
// Display
$result = mysql_query($search) or die('That query returned no results');
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<?php
while($result_arr = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{ 
?>
// Radio button
<input type="radio" name="radio">
<?php
echo $result_arr['cause_name']; 
echo " "; 
echo "<br>";
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="radio_submit" value="Select Item">
</form>
<?php
$anymatches=mysql_num_rows($result); 
if ($anymatches == 0) 
{ 
   echo "We don't seem to have that cause. You may add a cause by filling out a short <a href='add.php'>form</a>.<br><br>"; 
}
}
?>
<!--Sign Up Form-->
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="sign_up_form">
<input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Search" onFocus="this.select();" onMouseUp="return false;">
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
<br />
<br />
<input type="email" name="username" maxlength="250" placeholder="Your email" onFocus="this.select();" onMouseUp="return false;">
<input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="50" placeholder="Password" onFocus="this.select();" onMouseUp="return false;">
<input type="password" name="pass2" maxlength="50" placeholder="Re-type Password" onFocus="this.select();" onMouseUp="return false;">
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Your question is too theoretical. Can you provide something in points or if you can briefly explain

Comment: Before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because what you're doing here is full of severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). New code should not be using the deprecated `mysql_query` interface, it's being removed from future versions of PHP.

Comment: Ok, so @FakhruddinUjjainwala, I hope this can clarify
2 problems

-The radio option is not being submitted into the database
 -This is the big problem
-two forms, one database row.
 -Do I need to relate forms? how? using the previous id?

@ tadman, ok thank you I will look into preventing SQL injection.

Comment: Where is your radio button in above code? Can you format your code a bit

Comment: The radio button is generated by the PHP (so there is one radio button for every database result). the actual button is a few lines above the sign up form.

<?php
while($result_arr = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{ 
?>
<input type="radio" name="radio">
<?php
echo $result_arr['cause_name']; 
echo " "; 
echo "<br>";
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="radio_submit" value="Select Item">

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala, I also edited the code(there is a comment above where the radio button is.

Comment: `$result_arr['cause_name']; ` is this what should be the value for radio button?

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala, Yes it is. Note: I have tested the search part, and it works. The results from the query are displayed next to the radio buttons. Edit: Wait, I'm not sure...

Comment: try get mathod see what you get in url

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala Here is the end of the url

/index.php?radio=on&radio_submit=Select+Cause

Comment: did you try my suggestion?

Comment: INSERT INTO users (username, password, radio) VALUES ('tim', '1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72', '')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code like this

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="<?php echo $result_arr['cause_name']; ?>" >
```

and then submit it you should get the value

update the below query as well

```
<?php
echo $insert = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, radio) VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[pass]', '$_REQUEST[radio]')";
    $add_member = mysql_query($insert);
?>
```

change the below code

```
 //This code runs if the form has been submitted

 if (isset($_POST['radio_submit'])) {
```

/////

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
    {
        $radio = $_REQUEST['radio'];
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (radio) VALUE ('$radio')");

        if (!$insert)
        {
            echo mysql_error();
        }
    }


?> 

<form action="" method="get"> 
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="red">red 
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="blue">blue 
<input type="submit" name="submit" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: It still does not show anything in database. The url however changed to: /index.php?radio=bobby&radio_submit=Select+Cause   

Note:'bobby' was the result of the query that i checked with the radio and then submitted

Comment: can you paste the query that is going to insert the value into data base. really cant read your code.

Comment: This is the query (used for inserting everything):     // now we insert it into the database
  $insert = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, radio)
    VALUES ('".$_POST['username']."', '".$_POST['pass']."', '".$_POST['radio']."')";
  $add_member = mysql_query($insert);

Comment: paste what is getting echoed

Comment: Just tried it again. Here is what is being echoed: INSERT INTO users (username, password, radio) VALUES ('tim', '1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72', '')

Here is the url to my website. http://givingshops.com you can try searching the database for something (right now the only things you can search for are 'bob' because thats all I have in my database

Comment: where does it get echoed I cant see the echo on the page

Comment: your query? please paste it i am unable to find on your website

Comment: I can't get my query because my site just went down. Thats what you get with free web hosting...

Comment: ok so i search for something and this is the url: /index.php?radio=bobby&radio_submit=Select+Cause    I dont get anything echoed...

Comment: sorry did not get you

Comment: I was just saying, yes I updated it but to comment I need at least 15 characters

Comment: can i get your ftp details so that i can solve it my self if you can display the ftp on your site itself.

Comment: are you there online?

Comment: I would rather not give the password to my account online.

Comment: as you wish you can change it later on once the issue is resolved...any ways its upto you...earlier you told me that the query echoed right.. can you try the same code because as per my code the query should echo...and also work..if you can update me soon i an work upon it...as its almost 2am in India and I am feeling sleepy...btw may i know where are you from ? Just got from your profile chicago

Comment: or may be i can look into your matter tomorrow its simple ting and can be resolved

Comment: ok then just ping me once you are ol tomorrow...you can accept my answer if it helped you...if you still requie my help i am always there

Comment: I tried making the most basic radio button form to be submitted into a database. If I can get this form to work, I can figure out how to fix what I am currently working on. 

    <?php
        $insert = "INSERT INTO users (radio)
                VALUE ('$radio')";
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="<?php $radio ?>">red
    <input type="radio"  name="radio" value="<?php $radio ?>">blue
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>